# Need help in loading occupancy_grid map to OpenCV window

Tags: mapping, opencv

I have generated a `map` named `map_1.pgm` using `map_server` package. I want to display it in an OpenCV window. How can I achieve this?

I am currently trying this -

```
std::string file_name = "map_1.pgm"; 
cv::Mat m = cv::imread(file_name.c_str(), 0);

cv::namedWindow("map_1");
cv::imshow("map_one_window", m);

cv::waitKey(0);
```

This is my `map_1.yaml`

```
image: map_1.pgm
resolution: 0.050000
origin: [-100.000000, -100.000000, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

However, on doing the above steps, I get a big OpenCV window which is completely grey.

How do I solve this problem?

I am attaching the results of xdg-open map_1.pgm.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ROS maps, but the threshold values in the yaml seem to indicate your map values are floats in the [0,1] range. I think OpenCV will not properly visualize these.

Check the minimum/maximum values in your matrix.

Try to generate a uint8 image with values in the [0,255] range for display, by just multiplying your map values with 255 (you may even have to make it a 3-channel image [with 3 identical channels] for OpenCV to handle it properly).

Comment: I didn't get the last paragraph of your answer - 'Try to generate .......... 255'. 

The dimensions of m are 4000 * 4000. I also checked the maximum and minimum value of elements in m. The maximum value is 254 and minimum value is 0.

Comment: imshow works for me for a 1-channel uint8 matrix with values in [0,255] range.
grasping at straws.. check the type of m? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv
other than that, if the actual matrix  content is correct, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: related to the "content is correct".. I trust you checked the map image in a standard image viewer, right?

Comment: I am updating the post with the results of xdg-open map_1.pgm.

The type of m is '0' or 'CV_8U'.

Comment: When I resize both the dimensions of 'm' using the cv::resize function, I am able to see the white map surrounded by the grey space. I think, the image was always being displayed correctly. However, due to the large grey space surrounding the white map, I was not able to see the map. Reducing the size of m helped me to see the image.